# Automatically accessing the values of variable from workspace

Tags: matlab, variables

I am loading a loop in which different variables are loaded in every iteration. Name of each variable is different in each iteration. Is there anyway in Matlab to automatically access the value of that variable. So far I have tried like that:

```
for i=1:4
    str_load=strcat (fold_str, 'class_',class{:,i}, \Feeds_',files{:,i},'.mat');
    load(str_load)
    variables = who;
    var = strncmpi(variables,'Feed_A',6);
    chk=find(var==1);
    org_var=variables(chk,:);

end
```

I can have the name of the targeted variable in `org_var`. But How can I access values inside that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eval` function would evaluate the variable name and return its value:

```
value = eval('org_var');
```

But a better solution would be to capture the output of `load`:

```
data = load(str_load);
```

Instead of loading all the variables into your workspace (and potentially changing any of the variables you need in your loop), it loads them in a struct `data`. Now you have:

```
value = data.Feed_A;
```

You can also do

```
variables = fieldnames(data);
```

and if the variable name you need is in a string,

```
var = 'Feed_A';
value = data.(var);
```

Comment: `org_var` is a cell and it contains the name of variable 'Feed_A'. When I used `value = eval('org_val')`. It shows me the same variable name inside value 'Feed_A'. Can't have the data of Feed_A variable

Comment: When I try the `load`but how can i make it general because every file will load have different variable to use such as Feed_A, Feed_B, etc

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA: Updated the answer with some more ideas. I'm sure you can compose these into what you're looking for.